# Fails to build rosjava using Gradle

Tags: compile, build, rosjava-core, gradle, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried everything to get the package to compile using Gradle. I followed everything on the tutorials and installation. The only issue I have is when I try to compile it gives me this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.

> Could not find group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
> Required by:
> GpsMap:GpsMap:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT

It seems to not find the jar files created by the build of rosjava_core and rosjava.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Ralph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33472/fails-to-build-rosjava-using-gradle/) by [mikegulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2336/mikegulf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You either haven't added mavenLocal() to your repositories or you haven't executed the install task for rosjava_core.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0